# Generator threw an exception while rebinding

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I develop the front-end for the GPS-monitoring system. I need to add the new feature - geofence. I have created geofence model and its PropertyAccess interface.
When I compile the project I getting the error:

Here is the model of geofence:

```
public class Geofence extends JavaScriptObject {

protected Geofence() {}

public final native int getId() /*-{ return this.id; }-*/;
public final native String getName() /*-{ return this.name; }-*/;
public final native String getDescription() /*-{ return this.description; }-*/;
public final native Type getType() /*-{ return this.type; }-*/;
public final native Coordinate[] getCoordinates() /*-{ return this.coordinates; }-*/;
public final native double getRadius() /*-{ return this.radius; }-*/;
public final native int getUserId() /*-{ return this.userId; }-*/;

public final native void setId(int id) /*-{ this.id = id; }-*/;
public final native void setName(String name) /*-{ this.name = name; }-*/;
public final native void setDescription(String description) /*-{ this.description = description; }-*/;
public final native void setType(Type type) /*-{ this.type = type; }-*/;
public final native void setCoordinates(Coordinate[] coordinates) /*-{ this.coordinates = coordinates; }-*/;
public final native void setRadius(double radius) /*-{ this.radius = radius; }-*/;
public final native void setUserId(int userId) /*-{ this.userId = userId; }-*/;

public final String getEmpty() {
    return "";
}
}
```

and the interface to access its properties:

```
public interface GeofenceProperties extends PropertyAccess<Geofence> {

@Editor.Path("id")
ModelKeyProvider<Geofence> key();

ValueProvider<Geofence, Integer> id();
ValueProvider<Geofence, String> name();
ValueProvider<Geofence, String> description();
ValueProvider<Geofence, Coordinate[]> coordinates();
ValueProvider<Geofence, Double> radius();
ValueProvider<Geofence, Integer> userId();
ValueProvider<Geofence, String> empty();
}
```

Here is the error:

> Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
>            Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties'
>               Rebinding org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties
>                  Invoking generator com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator
>                     [ERROR] Generator 'com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties'
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.typesMatch(ValueProviderCreator.java:315)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.getSetterExpression(ValueProviderCreator.java:297)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.appendSetterBody(ValueProviderCreator.java:134)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.create(ValueProviderCreator.java:93)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.core.rebind.AbstractCreator.create(AbstractCreator.java:48)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator.generate(PropertyAccessGenerator.java:94)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:760)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:67)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:145)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:600)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:569)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1505)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:870)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1305)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1038)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:954)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:303)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:38)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:286)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.doCompile(Recompiler.java:333)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:161)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.recompile(Recompiler.java:119)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.recompile(Outbox.java:128)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.recompile(JobRunner.java:81)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.access$100(JobRunner.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner$2.run(JobRunner.java:73)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>            [ERROR] Errors in 'org/bitbucket/treklab/client/view/DeviceView.java'
>               [ERROR] Line 145: Failed to resolve 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties' via deferred binding
>            Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.resources.Resources'
>               Rebinding org.bitbucket.treklab.client.resources.Resources
>                  Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
>                     Preparing method cogWheel
>                        [WARN] Resource 'org/bitbucket/treklab/client/theme/icon/cogWheel.png' was located via ClassLoader. As a result changes in that resource will not be reflected in per-file recompiles. It should be registered via   or  entry in your .gwt.xml. In a future version of GWT, we will remove this fallback and your application will stop compiling
>            [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
>               [WARN] org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofencePropertiesImpl
>               [WARN] org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_coordinates_ValueProviderImpl
>            Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties'
>               Rebinding org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties
>                  Invoking generator com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator
>                     [ERROR] Generator 'com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties'
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.typesMatch(ValueProviderCreator.java:315)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.getSetterExpression(ValueProviderCreator.java:297)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.appendSetterBody(ValueProviderCreator.java:134)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.create(ValueProviderCreator.java:93)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.core.rebind.AbstractCreator.create(AbstractCreator.java:48)
>       at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator.generate(PropertyAccessGenerator.java:94)
>       at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:760)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation.traverse(JCastOperation.java:67)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:128)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement.traverse(JDeclarationStatement.java:49)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContext.traverse(JModVisitor.java:95)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemove(JModVisitor.java:351)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock.traverse(JBlock.java:92)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:149)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:145)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:83)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:600)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JConstructor.traverse(JConstructor.java:142)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:285)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.mainLoop(UnifyAst.java:1505)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst.exec(UnifyAst.java:870)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.unifyJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1305)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.constructJavaAst(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:1038)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler$Precompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:954)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(MonolithicJavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:303)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:38)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:286)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:206)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.doCompile(Recompiler.java:333)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.compile(Recompiler.java:161)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.recompile(Recompiler.java:119)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.recompile(Outbox.java:128)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.recompile(JobRunner.java:81)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner.access$100(JobRunner.java:34)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.JobRunner$2.run(JobRunner.java:73)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>            [ERROR] Errors in 'org/bitbucket/treklab/client/Application.java'
>               [ERROR] Line 43: Failed to resolve 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties' via deferred binding
>            [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
>               [WARN] org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_coordinates_ValueProviderImpl
>               [WARN] org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofencePropertiesImpl
>            Unification traversed 1267 fields and methods and 1208 types. 18 are considered part of the current module and 18 had all of their fields and methods traversed.
>            [WARN] Some stale types ([org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_description_ValueProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofencePropertiesImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_userId_ValueProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_coordinates_ValueProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_radius_ValueProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_name_ValueProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_id_ModelKeyProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_empty_ValueProviderImpl, org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.Geofence_id_ValueProviderImpl]) were not reprocessed as was expected. This is either a compiler bug or a Generator has legitimately stopped creating these types.
>         [ERROR] Compiler returned false
>         [WARN] recompile failed
>         [WARN] continuing to serve previous version

But when I change

```
Coordinate[]
```

to

```
List<Coordinate>
```

all works fine. Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator [ERROR] Generator 'com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.PropertyAccessGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'org.bitbucket.treklab.client.model.GeofenceProperties' java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sencha.gxt.data.rebind.ValueProviderCreator.typesMatch(ValueProviderCreator.java:315)...

From ValueProviderCreator.java:

```
private boolean typesMatch(JClassType a, JType b) {
  if (b.isPrimitive() != null) {
    return a.getQualifiedSourceName().equals(b.isPrimitive().getQualifiedBoxedSourceName());
  } else {
    assert b.isClassOrInterface() != null;

    return b.isClassOrInterface().isAssignableTo(a);
  }
}
```

This code (which I actually wrote several years ago, but I don't work for Sencha today) assumes either that the type in your bean property is either a primitive or an object (or interface). In GWT, apparently this excludes the possibility of using an array. From GWT's JArrayType:

```
public JClassType isClass() {
  // intentional null
  return null;
}
```

You'll need to file a bug with GXT itself to get this changed. However, your code might not work after this anyway (and almost certainly this is the root of your problem in [Can't parse JSON string to Java/JavaScriptObject in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589793/cant-parse-json-string-to-java-javascriptobject-in-gwt), your other question):

You can't have a JavaScriptObject's properties be non-JavaScript types. GWT's generated arrays *almost* look like js arrays, but will be missing important type details, and java.util.List won't work at all.

Instead, change your `getCoordinates` to return `JsArray<Coordinate>`.