# Can't parse JSON string to Java/JavaScriptObject in GWT

Tags: java, json, gwt, gxt

I receive data from the server in JSON and parse using JsonUtils (GWT). They look like this:

```
[{"id":26,"name":"Circle1","description":"Test","type":"CIRCLE","coordinates":[{"latitude":50.364736755649716,"longitude":30.120391845703125}],"radius":6577.427847903551,"userId":1}]
```

I use this code to parse it:

```
JsArray<Geofence> geofenceJsArray = JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText());
```

But I can't get access to the list of coordinates. When I call

```
geofenceJsArray.get(0).getCoordinates().size()
```

I receive this error message in browser's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $getCoordinates_1_g$(...).size_54_g$ is not a function
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add the source code for your `Geofence` Oject?

Comment: it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584497/generator-threw-an-exception-while-rebinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From my answer for [Generator threw an exception while rebinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584497/generator-threw-an-exception-while-rebinding/37593073#37593073), where you posted some of your source:)

You can't have a JavaScriptObject's properties be non-JavaScript types. GWT's generated arrays *almost* look like js arrays, but will be missing important type details, and java.util.List won't work at all - JS will happily pretend that it will work, and will return a JS array, which has a *property* called `length`, but no *method* called `size`.

Instead, change your `getCoordinates` to return `JsArray<Coordinate>`.